# Find real sd card path and write a file

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, sd-card

My device is htc one dual sim and for some reason Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is my  memory of the phone, it's not removable sd card.
I tried to find the real sd card path using this:

```
   public static HashSet<String> getExternalMounts() {
        final HashSet<String> out = new HashSet<String>();
        String reg = "(?i).*vold.*(vfat|ntfs|exfat|fat32|ext3|ext4).*rw.*";
        String s = "";
        try {
            final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount")
                    .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            process.waitFor();
            final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
                s = s + new String(buffer);
            }
            is.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // parse output
        final String[] lines = s.split("\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (!line.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("asec")) {
                if (line.matches(reg)) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    for (String part : parts) {
                        if (part.startsWith("/"))
                            if (!part.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("vold"))
                                out.add(part);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
```

And i got 
/mnt/media_rw/ext_sd

I tried to write files to /mnt/media_rw/ext_sd/downloads
but the file didn't appear to be created.

```
  File file = new File("/mnt/media_rw/ext_sd/downloads", "test.txt");
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write("sdfsdfsfd");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


02-11 23:12:35.236    9110-9110/www.jenyakirmiza.com.testsdcard W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/media_rw/ext_sd/downloads/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I heard smth about restriction starting from 4.4 so now we can't write files to removable sd card. But they said you can write filed to /sdcardpath/Android/data/your.package.name

ps. of course i added write_external permisssion to manifest.

Comment: You may wish to read more about what [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) mean from the standpoint of the Android SDK.

Comment: What an honour that you sir posted smth on my question. I used a lot of things you created. Thank you so much for such contribution to android community. i'll read everything you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all external storages with [`Context.getExternalMediaDirs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalMediaDirs()) and can check whether it is removable with [`Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(File)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageRemovable(java.io.File)). Note that Downloads directory will most likely be only in the primary (emulated) external storage.

Comment: there is one problem - this function appears onlu in android api lvl 21.

Comment: You can also use `Context.getExternalFilesDirs` or `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs` if you need to support older Android versions as well. To check if the external storage is removable, you can ask mount service in a way `Environment` does but I am not sure if that is possible in older Android versions.

Comment: @StenSoft It doesn't work on some devices. I'm sure that these devices have external SD card. But `getExternalFilesDirs` returns only the directory of primary storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) method :

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/", "test.txt");
```

and you can evaluate first if your file really exists with `exists()` method :

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/", "test.txt");
    if(file.exists()){

      FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write("sdfsdfsfd");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Very important to have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

inside your

```
 AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: i've already mentioned that device's memory is considered to be external, i want to write file to removable storage